# How to configure Jenkins to push changes from one Git repository to another if build is successful?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have read the option of "Merge before build". I want to do the same but instead of making the flow from an integration branch to the master branch within the same repository, I want to do it in the master branches of different repositories.

The workflow would be:

1. Developer pushes change to master branch in `repository_A`.
2. Jenkins polls `repository_A`, when it sees a change, it triggers the build flow.
3. If the build is successful, I want to push the changes in `repository_A` to master branch of `repository_B`.